# Why does Samsung access my contacts and storage if I use their store?

Tags: android, legal, phone

If I want to access the Galaxy Store on a Samsung Galaxy phone I have to agree to  a set of terms (Legal information). These terms are excerpted below:

> All content made available to you by the Samsung Galaxy Store is subject to the terms and conditions set forth below...
>
> In order to provide you with and further improve relevant services, the Samsung Galaxy Store accesses Phone, Contacts, and Storage. It also collections your device information (e.g. IMEI and model name) and service usage history...

I understand why it would collect "device information", as any software downloaded and installed on your device would operate best if the software is tailored for a specific device/OS version etc. I assume these are the same reasons why a web page is given the operating system and browser you are using to access that page.

However can anyone give a good reason why Samsung would access my contacts? I'm not exactly comfortable with this, especially as I don't see any reason for it for the purposes of making an ordinary app work. Also, when it says that it accesses my storage, does that mean that Samsung has access to my media stored on my phone? By that I mean documents, videos, photos etc?

Also I'm not sure if this question should be asked at another SE site maybe instead of here?

Comment: You already use a phone that was made by them.They could take any data if they wanted to

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question you should ask Samsung instead. They developed the app and thus they should know - we can only wildly speculate.